# What is complexity of following code?

Tags: c, performance, algorithm, time-complexity

Find the time complexity of following code.
Answer given is O(log(n)*n^1/2), but I am not getting it.
I want someone to explain this.

```
i=n;
while(i>0)
{
  k=1;
  for(j=1;j<=n;j+=k)
    k++;
  i=i/2;
}
```

Comment: It's not n^2.

The log(n) component comes from the fact that i is halved at each step. So, it's log(n) times something. I believe that the inner step grows with sqrt(n). Hence, log(n) * n^1/2

Comment: but can u prove how sqrt(n) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take this code segment:

```
k=1;
for(j=1;j<=n;j+=k)
  k++;
```

The values of `j` over various iterations will be `1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, ...`.

Note that these numbers have closed form `(m+1)(m+2)/2`, where `m` is the number of iterations that have gone by. If we want to know how many iterations this loop will run for, we need to solve `(m+1)(m+2)/2 = n`, which has solution `m = (sqrt(8n + 1) - 3))/2 = O(sqrt(n))`. So this loop will run `O(sqrt(n))` times.

The outer loop will run `O(log(n))` times (this is rather easy to see). So overall, we have `O(log(n)sqrt(n))`.

edit: Or perhaps easier than solving `(m+1)(m+2)/2 = n` directly would simply be to note that `(m+1)(m+2)/2 = O(m^2)`, and so `O(m^2) = n` implies `m = O(sqrt(n))`.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity would be :
(log n + 1)*(-1 + squareroot(1+4n))/2  = O(squareroot(n)*log n)

---

log n is in base 2.

Suppose n is 36.

The outer loop will iterate for log n + 1 times because the value is halved every time 36,18,9,4,2,1.

The inner loop has j values = 1,3,6,10,15,21,28,36.Every j value can be calculated as the sum of terms in AP 1+2+3+4+5....w = w(w+1)/2. So w(w+1)/2 = n.Solving this quadratic equation we get w=(-1+sqrt(1+4n))/2 i.e the number of iterations of inner loop.
For n=36, w=8.

Total complexity thus comes out to be : log n * sqrt(n).